# PHP add to beginning of array without reordering

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, addition

I've tried searching for an answer to my question but I couldn't find one that did it without reordering numerical indexes.

Is there a way to add a string to the beginning of an array without reordering the keys (numerical keys) without using a loop?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I'll try to explain the scenario. (I'm using CodeIgniter).

I have an array that is used throughout my app. This array is also used to create a dropdown and to validate these dropdown values in a form that I have. What I'd like to do is insert a blank value to the beginning of the array so that my dropdown has a blank option select by default.

So from this

1 => Hello
2 => World

to

'' => ''
1 => Hello
2 => World

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. Any example input/output?

Comment: What index should the new element have? Why do you need this condition (no reordering of the keys)? If you access the elements by key anyway, then the order does not matter. And if you iterate over them, then the index does not matter. So why do you need it? Maybe there is a better strategy for your case.

Comment: @BoltClock @Felix-Kling @yoda - I've tried to explain a bit in my original post - Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you don't want to change the numerical indexes i assume `array_unshift` will not work.

So maybe if you know the indexes you could do it like that:

```
$x = array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3); 
$y = array(1101 => 123);
var_dump( $y + $x );

/* Output:
array(4) {
  [1101]=>
  int(123)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
}
*/
```

Note that the key is now really in front of the array so `foreach` will work fine.

### Response to edit:

```
$x = array(1 => "Hello", 2 => "Welt"); 
$y = array("" => "");

var_dump($y + $x);

/*
array(3) {
  [""]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Welt"
}
*/
```

Comment: The problem with this method is if you have conflicting keys they will get overwritten.